# Why dart editor is still running

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I am very confuse about dart editor, how it works. When i run this application

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:dbcrypt/dbcrypt.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main() {

  //ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
  var receivePortPw = new ReceivePort();
  receivePortPw.listen((msg) {
     print(msg); 
  });


  Future<Isolate> f = Isolate.spawn(ReturnHashedPassword, receivePortPw.sendPort);
  f.then((Isolate i) {
    print('Print1 -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
    print('Print2 -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
  });
}

void ReturnHashedPassword(SendPort sendPort)
{
    print('ok');
    ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send('Isolate -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
    print('done');
}
```

the editor looks after, it is still running. Look at following printscreen, the terminate button(red square button) is not disable, it remember me, when i run a http server, this button is not gonna disable, until i manually do it.
[image]

Why the terminate button is not gonna disable here after output? It is only I/O application, it is not a webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listening running isolate. You can close it's port or simply kill it:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:dbcrypt/dbcrypt.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main() {

  //ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
  var receivePortPw = new ReceivePort();
  receivePortPw.listen((msg) {
     print(msg);
     receivePortPw.close();//stop listening.
  });


  Future<Isolate> f = Isolate.spawn(ReturnHashedPassword, receivePortPw.sendPort);
  f.then((Isolate i) {
    print('Print1 -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
    print('Print2 -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
    //i.kill(); // not nice...
  });
}

void ReturnHashedPassword(SendPort sendPort)
{
    print('ok');
    ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send('Isolate -> ' + new DBCrypt().hashpw('Password', new DBCrypt().gensalt()));
    print('done');
}
```