# How to end an isolate and how to get notified when the isolate was terminated

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-isolates

#### terminate isolate

When I want to end an isolate launched on the server created using `Isolate.spawn()` or `Isolate.spawnUri()`
how can I terminate the isolate.

`throw x` inside an isolate terminates the isolate when the exception is uncaught.
But I hope there is a more elegant solution.

`isolate.kill()` throws `Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: kill`

#### get notified

I guess when no more async operations are active the isolate ends (similar to `main`) but how can I know if the isolate has actually terminated?

Is there a way for the parent isolate to get notified when the child isolate terminates?
`isolate.addOnExitListener(_sendPort);` throws `Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: addOnExitListener`

#### ?

Are there alternative ways or do I have to wait until these methods are supported?

Comment: To clarify, you would like for isolate A to know if isolate B has shut down? Also, we should probably split this into two separate questions.

Comment: Exactly. The main isolate A spawns a new isolate B. After Bs work is done it should end. A doesn't really need a notification, this is just to verify that the method to end isolate B really works as expected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is the second part of the question is about something like `Future<ExitCode> Isolate.terminate()` ?  I think that if isolate isn't in a unresponsive state - it shouldn't be externally terminated. Otherwise it breaks encapsulation, because your code operates on assumption that the isolate B has no allocated resources(like DB connections, sockets etc.) which should be properly released.

Comment: @JAre You are right of course. I tried the child isolate B to send a message to the parent isolate A to notify it that B is ready to be killed but kill is not supported. I couldn't find terminate on the class or the instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Dart has a goal to be safe and easy to learn so I don't think that the standard API should enable bad coding practices. But it could use some sugar methods like `Future isolate.killYourself()` that will execute predefined termination callback inside the B isolate and returns Future in A isolate. If isolate B has no termination callback then the Future should hold error. this way user will be able to kill isolate only if it has proper mechanics.

Comment: I don't want bad coding practice. I'm just looking for a proper way to end an isolate. Currently the only way I found is to throw an exception. I don't think this is very elegant (especially the stack trace it prints to the console).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I thought that the `ReceivePort.close()` will terminate isolate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470247/why-dart-editor-is-still-running/24470692#24470692

Comment: Hmm, I found that the isolate can't terminate as long as the ReceivePort is not closed but this does not necessarily include that closing the ReceivePort terminate the isolate. This brings us to part 2 of my question. When I try this suggestion and close the ReceivePort, how can I verify that this made the isolate terminate?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Probably, you can check the number of thread in the DartVM process or memory consumption.

Comment: I thought of that but than I thought there has to be a better way and I asked on SO to see if I missed something basic. I'll investigate this further of course.

Comment: Might be @lrn can help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10977#c2

> The way to detect that an Isolate terminates after it has been
>   successfully    created is to use Isolate.addOnExitListener (possibly
>   also    Isolate.addErrorListener if needing to know why it
>   terminated).  Start the isolate paused, then when the Future
>   of Isolate.spawnUri    completes you can set up listeners and then
>   resume the isolate.
>
> So we have a way, it is still not implemented by the VM/Dartium, but
>   that's    another issue.

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/29775
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30425